# Google Maps request via lat-lng bounding box coordinates

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, coordinates, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

Is it possible to poll map graphics data from latlng bounding box coordinates? Xmin,XMax,Ymin,Ymax,Center in lat lng

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you using the Google Maps API? What data do you want exactly? Not sure what map graphics data is. BTW, if you want better answers you should accept more answers.

Comment: I mean the map tile images - I guess the most common reference to map graphics data..

Comment: I usually accept an answer when it works. A lot of the times the answers are incomplete... or there's no answer!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API and maps.google.com do not allow you to access map tiles directly. This violates the terms of service. However, if you just want map images, you can use the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), which does give you Google Maps Tiles.